# Upper bound for the nth derivative of $\Gamma(x)^n$

Tags: inequality, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds, integral-inequality, polygamma

I was trying to find an upper bound for

$$ \frac{d^n}{ds^n} \Gamma(s)^{n}|_{s=1}$$

yet, I only get the bound for the nth derivative of gamma, as follow:

First, the integral of the nth derivative of gamma is
$$\frac{d^n}{ds^n} \Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1} e^{-t} (\log t)^n dt$$

Note that this integral, if it changes sign, does so at $t=1$. So let us break it into two integrals,  one ranging from 0 to 1, the other from 1 to $\infty$.

$$I_n = \int_0^{1} e^{-t} (\log t)^n dt + \int_1^{\infty} e^{-t} (\log t)^n dt = K_n + L_n$$

Consider first $K_n$. We have that, in the $[0,1]$ interval, $\exp(-t)\leq 1$. Therefore we can bound

$$K_n = \int_0^{1} e^{-t} (\log t)^n dt\leq \int_0^{1}  (\log t)^n dt = (-1)^n n!.$$

For $L_n$ we can  do a change of variables $t \rightarrow t+1$ to write

$$L_n = \frac{1}{e} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-t)[\log (1+t)]^n dt.$$
Now note that $\log(1+t) \leq \sqrt{t}$ for all positive $t$. Therefore we can write
$$L_n \leq \frac{1}{e} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-t)t^{n/2} dt= \frac{1}{e} \Gamma\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right).$$

There, we can write

$$ \left|\frac{d^n}{ds^n} \Gamma(s)\right|_{s=1} \leq n!+\frac{1}{e} \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!$$

I've like to have some ideas of how to relate this bound with the bound I needed, or some way of writing $ \frac{d^n}{ds^n} \Gamma(s)^{n}|_{s=1}$ in terms of polygamma function if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the general Leibniz rule
$$
(f_1\dots f_m)^{(n)}=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_m=n}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}\prod_{i=1}^m f_i^{(k_i)}
$$
and get
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}s^n}[\Gamma(s)^n]\right\rvert_{s=1} = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=n}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}\prod_{i=1}^n \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k_i}}{\mathrm{d}s^{k_i}}\Gamma(s)\right\rvert_{s=1}.
$$

There is an error in your derivation.  Since $\log t<0$ for $t\in(0,1)$, and you bound $0<e^{-t}<1$, your bound for $K_n$ doesn't work with the $(-1)^n$.  If you put everything in modulus sign you get $\lvert K_n\rvert\leq n!$ which seems to be what you were doing at the end.

Comment: I attempted to upper bound this derivative using the Leibniz rule, but unfortunately, it seems to be a little complicated. Can you give me some enlightenment on this? And you are right, I should say that $ |I_n| \leq |K_n| + |L_n|$.

Comment: It would be easier if you weaken your bound to, for example, $\lvert I_n\rvert\leq 2^n n!$.